# Unit test with redux-mock-store - How can I make this unit test pass?

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme, jestjs, redux-mock-store

I've just started using jest and enzyme.

I'm having a problem to make my unit test work.
Im using redux-mock-store to mock store object.

```
it('shows an li for each comment', () => {
    expect(container.find('li').length).toBe(2);
});
```

I'm expecting two li elements but I got 0 li elements.

I've got stuck in this error for a long time.

Could anyone please help me to figure out how to make this test pass, please!?

## test result from jest test runner

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
    2
Received:
    0
Expected :2
Actual   :0
```

## CommentList.test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import CommentList from '../../components/CommentList';
jest.unmock('../../components/CommentList');

describe('CommentList', () => {

    const initialState = {comments: ['New Comment', 'Other New Comment']};
    const mockStore = configureStore();

    let store;
    let container;

    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        container = shallow(<CommentList store={store} />);
    });

    //This passes.
    it('renders the connected component', () => {
        expect(container.length).toBe(1);
    });

    //This fails.
    it('shows an li for each comment', () => {
        expect(container.find('li').length).toBe(2);
    });

});
```

## CommentList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

const CommentList = (props) => {

    const list = props.comments.map((comment) => {

        <li key={comment}>{comment}</li>
    });

    return (
        <ul className="comment-list">
            {list}
        </ul>
    )

};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        comments: state.comments
    }
}

CommentList.propTypes = propTypes;
CommentList.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CommentList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work like that if you render your component using `mount` instead of `shallow` inside your `beforeEach()`.

With shallow rendering the renderer is not going as deep as to show your `li` components, because the tree will be connect(CommentList) -> CommentList -> ul -> li

You can also use `dive` to go one level deeper if needed, in case you want to stay shallow. See in the docs:
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html

Comment: Thanks!! I got it!

Answer (score 1):

You can either export not decorated CommentList component and test in by just passing comments props or you can try to wrap the CommentList component with the Provider and pass the store to it.

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <CommentList />
</Provider>
```

More information you can find here:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components

In order to make your example work you have to change list to:

```js
const list = props.comments.map(comment => (
    <li key={comment}>{comment}</li>
));
```

Comment: I've tried both ways but I still got the same error in my test. Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: I've read this article(https://medium.com/@gethylgeorge/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9) before I wrote this test code.

Comment: @Hayatomo The reason it is not working is that there is an issue in the way you are rendering comments: `map` function has to return value in your code it does nothing.

Comment: Year!! You are right! Thank you for catching the mistake... It was one of the reasons why this test didnt work...